# Can I conditionally take over a key binding in vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working with a syntax that handles comments differently from most languages. It's BASIC, which means that a comment toggle goes from:

```
10 PRINT "Hi"
```

To

```
10 REM PRINT "Hi"
```

So currently I've used the following (type) of code:

```
// register on vscode's default comment toggle
vscode.commands.registerCommand('editor.action.commentLine', () => {
  if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.languageId !== 'nextbasic') {
    // if this isn't our language give control back…?
    return;
  }

  // … handle my own bespoke comment method
})
```

The problem I've got is that once the extension is activated, **all** comment toggling goes through my code and the early return statement just results in commenting not working at all (outside of my `nextbasic` language).

Does anyone know if there's a way to say: let the original `command.action.commentLine` handle this if the language doesn't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a cleaner solution would be to make a command with a different ID, and either tell your users to add a keybinding for it or use `contributes.keybindings` in `package.json`. This keybinding should have a `when` condition that checks the active language ID.

```json
"contributes": {
    "keybindings": [
        {
            "command": "myExtension.commentLine",
            "key": "ctrl+oem_2",
            "when": "editorLangId == 'nextbasic'"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that this doesn't account for users that have customized the keybinding for the builtin `commentLine` command.

Other than that, you could maybe listen for `onDidChangeActiveEditor` events and unregister / register your command dynamically depending on language ID (you can unregister with the `Disposable` that is returned on registration). I'm not sure if the built-in command is restored on unregistration though, since registering a command with an ID that already exists is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Thanks - took that approach and sorted it  (the contribute keybinding in the package contributions)